# Jquery call another function after ajax in loop is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that runs inside a loop and is dependent on the amount of items in the array. How do I run another function after the ajax call is done and outside the loop? Is it possible?

This is the function

```
function downloadAll(){
    downloads = [];
    $.each(checked, function(key, value) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url($this->data['controller'].'/Download/'); ?>",
            data:'id='+value,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.loading').show();
            },
            success: function(data){
                downloads.push(data);
                $('.loading').fadeOut("slow");
            },
        });
    }); 
    processZip(downloads);
}
```

Comment: You can try by keeping a counter and increment it in success and check if(counter==checkedItemlength) then call processZip(downloads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with *after all calls succeded* which is quite easy:

```
success: function(data){
      downloads.push(data);
      $('.loading').fadeOut("slow");
      if(downloads.length===checked.length){//suppose checked is array like
        alert("finish");
      }
 },
```

*Outside of the loop* is more difficult as it isnt really a loop and it requires some modifications. You basically want to await multiple Promises (Promise.all):

```
Promise.all(checked.map(function(value){
 return Promise(function(resolve){
  $.ajax({... ,success:resolve});
 });
})).then(function(downloads){
 console.log("finished",downloads);
});
```

Comment: Oh! I think the check the downloads length matches the checked length is great! Thank you!